# How to model a many to many from a DDD perspective in UML?

Tags: uml, domain-driven-design

I have a two entity objects Site and Customer where there is a many to many relationship. I have read you try not to model this in DDD as it is in the data model and go for a unidirectional flow.

If I wanted to show this in UML, would I show it as it is in the data model:

`Site * ----->*Customer` but the direction arrow gives the flow?

or as following

`Site ----->*Customer` But then this would imply that Customer can only go in one site.

Comment: "I have read you try not to model this in DDD"?  Can you provide the quote or the link?

Comment: Is this the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909384/many-to-many-relationship-in-ddd

Comment: @S.Lott "I have read you try not to model this in DDD" => as far as I remember, towards the first third of the DDD book, Evans explains that bidirectional associations (either many-to-many or one-to-many) are cumbersome and he gives examples of how to turn them into one-directional associations. Namely, a Site's Customers collection must be kept in sync with all the Site collections of the Customers which might be hard to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The sense I get from this [article](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/01/24/ddd-many-to-many-object-relational-mapping/) is that within the realm of DDD, `Site--->*Customer` does not indicate that a Customer cannot be related to more than one site.  Rather, it simply indicates that a Site can have multiple Customers (as in a list of them) whereas, the Customer treats each Site as a unique interaction and does not maintain a list of Sites.

This makes some sense.  The Site is a Site, whether or not anyone visits it.  The Customer, on the other hand, only becomes a Customer upon visiting a Site.